# PyArrow not Writing to Feather or Parquet

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

So looking at the docs for [write_feather](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.feather.write_feather.html) I should be able to write an Arrow table as follows.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.feather as fe


fe.write_feather(
  pa.Table.from_arrays([ pa.array([1,2,3]) ], names=['value']), 'file.feather'
)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "pyarrow/feather.py", line 89, in write
    if not df.columns.is_unique:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_unique'
```

Parquet files seem to write as expected, so I'm thinking there might be a bug in Feather. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `pyarrow.feather.write_feather` expects a `pandas.DataFrame` and not a `pyarrow.Table` in the version of `pyarrow` you are using. If you directly want to write a `pyarrow.Table`, you need to upgrade to a more recent version as this support was only recently added.